# Is it possible to create a C# compile time Method?

Tags: c#

I've been wondering if it is possible, using Visual Studio 2015 or other versions, create a method or something like "nameof" or "typeof" that runs on compile time?

If so could you provide a basic "how to" example.

Comment: Alter the C# compiler. You can download the source code from Github.

Comment: You can use Roslyn for code generation at compile time.

Comment: Could you provide the compiler source code link?

Comment: @poke the goal is not to generate code per se but to have a compiler time method.